# Why does -0 === 0 evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript

According to what I've read, all numbers in JavaScript are saved as floats except array indexes and the operands of bitwise operations.

Because all floats have a sign bit `-0 === 0` should evaluate to false.  However it evaluates to true.

Comment: Oh, shoot. Don't launch the satellite! Abort! Abort!

Comment: Your question title is extremely misleading since -0===0 evaluates to true.

Comment: They are different, but they evaluate to true because the spec for how numbers work says, in no uncertain terms, that's what should happen.

Comment: The spec states that it returns true.. What other answer do you need?

Answer (score 6):

Because JS uses the IEEE 754 standard for floating point numbers, which states that `-0` and `+0` should "compare as equal with the usual (numerical) comparison operators." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons))